# How can I store the parameters passed in multiple requests to a same CGI?

Tags: perl, cgi

I have two different Perl CGIs as below which creates two HTMLs.

tes1.pl is called from test.html as a POST call with a param.
test2.pl will be called from test1.pl. But here is the problem, there is a link in test2.pl to test1.pl.
So. when the link is clicked all the POST params will be gone since this runs in a different context.
Can some one let me know how to tackle this situation?

test.html:

```
<form id = "test" action ="./tes1.pl" method="POST" target="_blank">
  <input type="hidden" id='param_sender' name="param1" value="">
 </form>
 <a onclick="setValue();document.getElementById('test').submit();">SEND THE VALUE</td></tr>
```

test1.pl:

```
use CGI;
$page=CGI::new();
my $method=$page->request_method;
if ($method eq "POST") {
  my $gpmsc_user=$page->param('param1');
}
print $page->header,
"<link rel='stylesheet' href='./test.css' type='text/css'>";
print $page->start_html(-title=>"TEST1");
```

test2.pl

```
my $page= new CGI();
print $page->header,
"<link rel='stylesheet' href='./test.css' type='text/css'>";
print $page->start_html(-title=>'TEST2');
print $page->startform(-method=>post,-action=>'test3.pl');
print $page->append,
"<table border=true>
 <tr class=amhead>
  <td colspan=3>
  <br><a href='test1.pl'>Return to Test1</a>
  </td>
 </tr>..."
```

Comment: Your example is really confusing. You're not showing any of that calling. I think what you meant is that the user is jumping between different scripts. If you have to do CGI, have a look at CGI::Session. You want to retain data per user in the backend across multiple requests, so you want a session.

Comment: test.html has an anchor tag to submit the form which calls test.pl
test2.pl has an anchor tag where there is link to test1.pl.
Is this what you are referring to?

But, you are true, i need to retain the data across multiple requests to the same CGI

Answer (score 2):

You don't have two CGI programs calling each other. You have a couple of Perl programs that output HTML forms. As such, if you want the one form to have the same parameters in the form, you have to create the HTML in way that has the values set as the default values for those inputs.

With the now-deprecated CGI features,

```
use CGI qw(:html :form);

my $cgi = CGI->new( 'veggie=tomato' ); # from first form

my $field = 'veggie';
my $value = $cgi->param(
    -name  => $field,
    );

print textfield(  # create second form
    -name    => $field,
    -default => $value,
    );
```

This outputs:

```
<input type="text" name="veggie" value="tomato" />
```

But, as the `CGI` docs note, these HTML generators are deprecated and shouldn't be used. The docs list some alternatives.

Comment: That's true. I need to re-word it They are creating two different HTMLs. test1.pl can be called from #1 test.html and #2 test2.pl, How can i store the params sent by #1 and use them when called from #2.